# ASP.net MVC EF Codefirst duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, duplicates

Using Asp.net MVC 4 and EF 5.0

**THE PROBLEM:**

Whenever I choose a user in the dropdownlist and submit the post to the Action. 
Two things happen:

1. The user is added to the DinnerEvent as supposed to:
2. The User that was selected is duplicated, so that I now have two instances of the user in the User table in the database. Which is bad. :(

***Here is the setup***

**I have created two entities:
 DinnerEvent and User**

The DinnerEvent class has a navigation property to a collection of Attendants (Users)

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Attendants { get; set; }
```

I have created repositories for both DinnerEvent and Users

The **AddAttendantToEvent Action** in the **DinnerEvent Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAttendantToEvent(int users  , int EventID )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = userRepository.Find(users);
        dinnereventRepository.Find(EventID).Attendants.Add(user); //Add the User to the Event.
        dinnereventRepository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**The view** - Iterating over all the events, and adding a dropdownlist populated with all the users foreach event.

```
 @model Madklub.Models.ViewModel

 @foreach (var item in Model.events) {

 //Code to display available events

     @using (Html.BeginForm("AddAttendantToEvent", "DinnerEvents")) {

     @Html.Hidden("EventID", item.DinnerEventID);
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.users, new SelectList(Model.users, "UserID", "RoomNumber"));

     <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<DinnerEvent> events { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

which is initialized like this:

**Index Action in DinnerEventController:**

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    ViewModel viewdata = new ViewModel();
    viewdata.events = dinnereventRepository.AllIncluding(m => m.Attendants);
    viewdata.users = userRepository.All;
    return View(viewdata);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**The repository code as requested:**

Scaled down to only contain the Save() method.

Note that this is all autogenerated code by Scaffolding.

```
public class DinnerEventRepository : IDinnerEventRepository
{
    MadklubContext context = new MadklubContext();

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }        
}

public class MadklubContext : DbContext
 {     

   public DbSet<Madklub.Models.User> Users { get; set; }

   public DbSet<Madklub.Models.MadklubEvent> MadklubEvents { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your Repositories?

Comment: I've added the repository code , note: that this is all autogenerated code.

Comment: @KristianGrønborgNissen, the reason for the duplication is, you are adding a detached entity (So EF doesnt know it exists) to the Event, thus when you save changes, it adds it.

Comment: I think that Johan is right, you must be adding a detached object. Does the Find method detach the object?

Comment: How can i reattach it, or avoid it from being detached in the first place?

Comment: use the Unit of Work pattern; create a class that has an instance of each repository and pass a single DbContext instance to each repository so that they share the same DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit of Work pattern: (BTW, make your repo's/uow IDisposable so you can clean up the DbContext instances)

```
public class DinnerEventRepository : IDinnerEventRepository
{
    MadklubContext _context = new MadklubContext();

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }  

    public DinnerEventRepository( MadklubContext context = null )
    {
        _context = context ?? new MadklubContext();
    }      
}

public class UserRepository //: IUserRepository
{
    MadklubContext _context = new MadklubContext();

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }  

    public UserRepository( MadklubContext context = null )
    {
        _context = context ?? new MadklubContext();
    }      
}

public class RsvpUnitOfWork // come up with a better name
{
    MadklubContext _context = new MadklubContext();

    public DinnerEventRepository DinnerEventRepo { get; private set; }
    public UserRepository UserRepo { get; private set; }

    public RsvpUnitOfWork()
    {
        DinnerEventRepo = new DinnerEventRepository( _context );
        UserRepo = new UserRepository( _context );
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAttendantToEvent(int users  , int EventID )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // this should be a using statement once you implement IDisposable
        // e.g. using( var uow = new RsvpUnitOfWork() ) { ... }
        var uow = new RsvpUnitOfWork();
        // you need to validate that user != null
        var user = uow.UserRepo.Find(users);
        // possible null reference exception if dinner event not found for EventID
        uow.DinnerEventRepo.Find(EventID).Attendants.Add(user); //Add the User to the Event.
        uow.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks alot. So the issue was, that the repositories were not using the same instance of DbContext?!

Comment: Yes - you were introducing the `User` object from the `UserRepository`'s context into the `DinnerEventRepository`'s context, which made it appear to be new and therefore an add/insert operation.